# Meaning of `get functionname() {...}` within Javascript object

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I've been looking over the GNOME shell javascript interface and noticed the following snippet (`popupMenu.js` for those who are interested) from the prototype of a class:

```
PopupSwitchMenuItem.prototype = {
    __proto__: PopupBaseMenuItem.prototype,

    _init: function(text, active, params) {
        ... (code)
    },

    ... function definitions

    get state() {
        return this._switch.state;
    },

    ... more functions
};
```

Could anyone explain to me what the `get state() { ... }` means? I thought everything had to be of the form `name: value` within a javascript object? (If I make one of these objects I can do `obj.state` which returns what I assume is `this._switch.state`).

It may help to note that GNOME say they use a flavour of javascript (gjs) similar to Mozilla's Spidermonkey, so is this behaviour a non-standard javascript behaviour and a feature of spidermonkey/gjs?

Also, is there documentation pertaining to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get and John Resig's post at http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

The interesting thing is that you access the properties just like any other property, except they are dynamically created... in example

```
foo = {
  get blah() {
    return "bar";
  }
}

foo.blah == "bar"
```

Without native getters you would have to do `foo.blah()`. Frankly I've never used them simply because IE8 doesn't support it, and the advantage is just so minor. Most commonly I can see them being useful in a situation where I started with a "dumb" property like foo.blah, and at some point later in the development cycle realized that I wanted foo.blah(), and had to do the conversion at every point, while with the getters and setters such a conversion is unneccessary, since you simply change the object definition.